# How to change the color of Editor cursor on Maui iOS?

Tags: .net, maui

How can I change the color of the cursor in the Editor control on a Maui iOS app?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

While renderers (from the other answer) still work, you shouldn't be using it anymore. That only exists for compatibility reasons with Xamarin.Forms.

What you want to do is create a modify the mapper. The official docs on how to do that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize).

If you want to do this for all `Entry` controls in your app, you can do this:

```cs
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("CursorColor", (handler, view) =>
{
#if IOS
    handler.PlatformView.TintColor = UIKit.UIColor.Green;
#endif
});
```

Place this anywhere you like somewhere in the startup of your app. Maybe in your `MauiProgram.cs`.

If you want to do this for a specific instance of an `Entry` you want to create an inheritance and check for that in the above code. For instance, that would look like this:

```cs
class MyGreenEntry : Entry
{
}

Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("CursorColor", (handler, view) =>
{
#if IOS
    if (view is MyGreenEntry)
    {
        handler.PlatformView.TintColor = UIKit.UIColor.Green;
    }
#endif
});
```

I've created a little sample here: https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiCustomCursorColoriOSSample and written more about it in a blog post here: https://blog.verslu.is/maui/change-cursor-color-maui-ios/

*Edit: oops, just noticed that this is about the Editor. All the same basically applies, but make sure to use the `EditorHandler` instead of the `EntryHandler` and of course inherit from the `Editor` if you want to use it only on one type. I updated the sample code in the repo just above here to also include the code for `Editor`.*

Comment: Super!  Just a tip: If it's about `Entry` then there's an easier way to set or get the cursor color. The `Entry.SetCursorColor` method, in the `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific` namespace, sets the cursor color to a specified Color. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/platform-specifics/entry-cursor-color.

Comment: Sorry for the offtopic but I think this might be useful to someone.
ANDROID:
1. Change "CURSOR COLOR":
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("CursorColor", (handler, view) =>
    {
#if __ANDROID__
        handler.PlatformView.TextCursorDrawable.SetTint(Colors.Green.ToAndroid());
#endif
    }); 
2. Change "SELECTED TEXT COLOR"
change the color in the Platforms -> Android -> Resources -> values -> colors.xml -> "colorAccent"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Using Custom Renderers](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI) in .NET MAUI to achieve it.

Below are the detailed steps:

1. Create the `MyEditor.cs` in the Project folder:

```
public class MyEditor : Editor 
{

}
```

2. Create the platform-specific implementation file `MyEditorRenderer.cs` under **Platform/iOS**:

```
[Obsolete] 
public class MyEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
     {
          base.OnElementChanged(e);

          if (Control != null)
          {
              Control.TintColor = UIColor.Green;
      }

   }
}
```

3. Register our handlers like below in the `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
       .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
       {

#if IOS
             handlers.AddHandler(typeof(MyEditor), typeof(MyEditorRenderer));

#endif
       });
```

4. Finally, create an instance for the editor control and then run it to check.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="MAUIProjectWithRenderer.MainPage"
xmlns:editor="clr-namespace:CustomRenderer"
>

<VerticalStacklayout>
    <editor:MyEditor /> 
</VerticalStacklayout>

</ContentPage>
```